# Расшифровать ссылку онлайн тв трансляции канала

Tags: rtmp

Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
 <div id="boxonline6" class="hidden_video">
 <div style="background:#E4E4E4; height:354px">
<object id="videoplayer5447" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://ovego.3dn.ru/file/uppod.swf" width="560" height="360"><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="movie" value="http://ovego.3dn.ru/file/uppod.swf"><param name="flashvars" value="uid=videoplayer5447&amp;comment=tro&amp;st=62AEZBUTcLSOfNxaoijYnypdQVQm56T2M3R5SGfLkwiYj5nG2BQWRW5ntu0c9BMrt&amp;file=62ATaJ5EbIdGfRSa8=uOlK43QD635hzmQV9sv0oLSwhp30cYs35T7W5ntu0o9v0rH"></object>
```

Где то тут есть зашифрованная ссылка на онлайн тв вещание канала 2x2....скорее всего в rtmp вот она мне то и нужна....прошу вас помогите её узнать...заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: вот она

    =videoplayer5447&amp;comment=tro&amp;st=62AEZBUTcLSOfNxaoijYnypdQVQm56T2M3R5SGfLkwiYj5nG2BQWRW5ntu0c9BMrt&amp;file=62ATaJ5EbIdGfRSa8=uOlK43QD635hzmQV9sv0oLSwhp30cYs35T7W5ntu0o9v0rH

а вот как это расшифровать... это нужно смотреть внутрь плеера uppod.swf.

Или просто обратитесь к каналу 2на2. Попросите ссылку.

Comment: Ну вот именно в этом месте и скрыта ссылка на онлайн поток...да причёи тут 2x2 это не их онлайн тв.